# Travis fails finding my .travis.yml

Tags: travis-ci

I got a warning log like this and my builds have been failed.

```
WARNING: We were unable to find a .travis.yml file. This may not be what you
want. Build will be run with default settings.
```

But there have existed .travis.yml in my repo.
This issue seems to be caused after I changed my repo name on Github.
(Before changes it, Travis could detect my .travis.yml)

My environment is there: https://travis-ci.org/PizzaFactory/mRDT

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hmm... It was fixed automagically after I committed an another files and pushed.
It already works to me. But there seems an issue in Travis-CI builder.

Answer (score 5):

It was happening probably because you renamed the repo on GitHub.

What I did in order to fix the problem is to go in Travis `Accounts` section, press the `Sync` button and then push another commit to the repo.